# Understanding the function CAP_PROP_FPS in cv2

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to understand the output frames I received using the code below. I am learning to use OpenCV and how it functions. My idea is to get one frame per second in a video. Here are some of the stats. The video is 25 fps and it is 18 seconds long. When I run the code, I am getting 19 frames outputted.

```
def capture(dataset,folder_name):
    for i in np.arange(len(dataset)):
        video_name=dataset.video_name[i]
        video_read_path=os.path.join(video_directory,video_name)
        cap=cv2.VideoCapture(video_read_path)
        
        write_file=os.path.join(os.path.join(Events_path,folder_name),
                                  video_name.split(".")[0])
        cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 20)
        frameRate=cap.get(5)
        x=1
        count=0
        while(cap.isOpened()):
            frameId = cap.get(1) #current frame number
            ret, frame = cap.read()
            if (ret != True):
                break
            if (frameId % math.floor(frameRate) == 0):
                filename ="frame%d.jpg" % count;count+=1

                cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(write_file,filename), frame)
            cap.release()
        return print("All frames written in the: "+folder_name+" Folder")

capture(set,'Video_set')
```

I have used cap.get 1 frame per second and what is the use of CAP_PROP_FPS here. To my understanding, it will resize the fps from the original video fps to what I set here? If that is the case what is so different with not setting this up? Can someone please help me understand it and the use of this? Thanks.

Comment: Depends on the VideoIO backend used. Impossible to say here, since your code example in incomplete and crucially omits the in initialization of `cap`. | However, unless you're reading from a camera, it's useless.

Comment: @DanMašek I updated my entire code. Now, this might help.

Comment: OK. So you're reading from files, therefore changing the FPS property will have no effect. `VideoCapture` will just read the frames from the file as fast as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this line of code `cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 20)` into `cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, the_max_fps_of_camera_check_manual_ofCamera)`. Because this part of the code sets the fps of the video input received from the camera, you have set it to 20 and need to change it to the max of the camera input, or even 25 which is of the video. But this also depends on the processing speed of the computer and other factors as well, but the computer will try to get the video in the max fps of the camera as is set. It will not get more than the max fps of the camera but might get less than that.

Comment: Yes, this line of code sets the refresh rate of the camera hardware which usually is 30 fps. `cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 30)`.

Comment: @Bixo I use that and it is correct most of the times.